# Selenium WebDriver Extjs sample code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ext.net

In a short time I will begin automating a web site that has ext.net controls in it. I actually tried to automate a simple scenario as a sample from "http://examples.ext.net/" site. Click > Form > Field Note > Overview but I couldn't manage to write text to simple note textbox. Could you provide a code sample that is working? I tried to get by XPath and other means that can be used with by class. If I try to get all the inputs I get them but SendKeys or Click methods don't work. I get Element Not Visible exception. Could you provide a code sample that is working?

```
    IWebElement htmlElement = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("html"));
    IList<IWebElement> inputList = htmlElement.FindElements(By.TagName("input"));
```

(I get all the inputs but I can't write note...)

Comment: Just to clarify, a field's note is not an input, it is a div.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following in Java and you can easily convert it to C# if you choose to.
I use a utility method to first properly query for the correct element:

```
class Utils
{
      public WebElement query(String componentQuery) {

        String query =  componentQuery;
        String cmd = String.format("Ext.ComponentQuery.query('%s')[0]", query);
        String js = "return " + cmd + ".id;";
        String id = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js);
        return driver.findElement(By.id(id));
      }
 }
```

Then you can get your component here:

```
WebElement componentElement=Utils.query("Your-ExtJS-Query-for-the-component-goes-here"+".inputEl");
componentElement.sendKeys(valuesToSet)
```